# Making a lookup readonly?

Tags: lookup

I tried to make a lookup read only from page layout and tried it from profile. But I am not able to make it read only on my standard page. Is it possible to make a lookup read only. Because we have lookup from pick up a record and relate it with. So is it possible, then why is the business logic behind this.

Answer (score 3):

Please find solution at below link :

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008rSEIAY

> if you want to make this field readonly from all the interface for any
>   or all the profiles then you need to go to field level security. Setup
>   -> Security Controls-> Field Accessibility -> now select the object which contains this field. Then click on View by Fields. Now select
>   your field from the drop down. Next to the profile for which you want
>   this field to be read only click on editable or hidden. From the next
>   page under Field level security select 'Read only'.

Comment: Did you tried that out. I am not able to get the solution when I tried it. That I mention in my question I tried from profile, security, page layout .

Comment: Are you trying to check this using System Admin profile ? For Admin, it will always be editable. Can you please try to check it from other profiles ?

Comment: Hey @S.Sharma, I added some content from the link to the answer as the answer got flagged as being low quality. Generally you should always add the relevant content as if the link breaks the answer will no longer be of any use without it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by Field level security on object but alternatively,
you can create a validation rule on object:

```
ISCHANGED( LookupFieldAPI__c )
```

This will prevent user from updating the record.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will also prevent any process or api integration from updating the field. That may not be the intention.